# How to set desired device orientation for face up / face down orientation

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in which I am setting different nibs for portrait and landscape mode. My app rotates for both portrait and both landscape orientations ,but faceup / facedown orientation.

when I put my device in faceup / facedown orientation , it shows none of the nibs. I compromised with logic and set the device orientations programmatically  in **viewWillAppear** like in this way

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationUnknown || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]==UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown) 
        [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];      
    else
        [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]];           
}
```

when this view controller loads  , this logic works perfectly but after navigating from this to another view controller and when I come back to this view controller (by calling  popViewControllerAnimated: method ) , all above statements get executed properly (it executes **IF statement**) and it sets the portrait nib but doesn't rotate the device. It sets Portrait nib in Landscape mode.

My **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method looks like this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {


    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))      
     {
           // code to set landscape nib
           // there is no error in this code and it works properly
     }      
    else if ((interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))  
    {
        //code to set portrait nib
  // there is no error in this code and it works properly
    }           
    return YES;
}
```

I Searched in a lot of websites and applied all their logics , yet none of them worked. Kindly help me to fix this problem.

Thanks.